# HTML2PDF Image Error Impossible to Load the Image

Tags: php, html, pdf, converters, html2pdf

I am using HTML2PDF and I am trying to make images appear but I keep on getting this error:

ERROR nÂ°6
File : /var/www/vhosts/default-domain.com/httpdocs/html2pdf_v4.03/html2pdf.class.php
Line : 1321

Impossible to load the image /student/questions 3rd/images/small1324538668Number Lines 5.JPG

Can anybody please help me with this issue?  I have been struggling with it for a while already.

This is the html code that I have.

```
     <img src="/student/questions 3rd/images/small1324538668Number Lines 5.JPG" />
```

And here is the site to check to see how it works.

http://www.domain.com/html2pdf_v4.03/examples/Test.php

Please help!!

Thank You

Comment: when i check for the image on your server its not where that url says it should be

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While using HTML2PDF yo have to give the full path of your image like in this manner

```
   http://domain/path/to/image
```

or you can give student/questions 3rd/images/small1324538668Number Lines 5.JPG because any script runs on base of index.php which is located in root so you have to give the image path from root location.

Comment: I completely understand.  I will check it out tonight and will let you know if it works.

Comment: Will the image data be embed into the resulting pdf?

Comment: what do you mean by this path? student/questions 3rd/images/small1324538668Number Lines 5.JPG

Comment: Using full physical path from server root worked for me:

<img src="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])  ?>/student/questions 3rd/images/small1324538668Number Lines 5.JPG" />

Answer (score 6):

HTML2PDF failed to load image on image src when allow_url_fopen is not enabled in the server. There is another solution who have not access to enable allow_url_fopen. Solution is to use image base64 encoded data as image source. Example code below.

```
<?php
 $path =  'directory/example.jpg';
 $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $data = file_get_contents($path);
 $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $base64 ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, my image src attribute was an absolute path and it still wasn't working:

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg"/>
```

I had to enable `allow_url_fopen` on the server

Comment: This was the correct answer for me as well. I enabled allow_url_fopen in php.ini